# Why do some classes like the java regex Pattern class do not have any public constructors?

Tags: java, regex

The `Pattern` class requires you to use it's `public static compile()` method in order to create a `Pattern`. What is the reasoning behind this? Also, is this a good example of the Factory design pattern?

Comment: The reasoning is that they want you to use the static method to create the object, not a constructor.  And yes, it is a good example of a Factory.  From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern:

Comment: *"Creating an object often requires complex processes not appropriate to include within a composing object. The object's creation may lead to a significant duplication of code, may require information not accessible to the composing object, may not provide a sufficient level of abstraction, or may otherwise not be part of the composing object's concerns. The factory method design pattern handles these problems by defining a separate method for creating the objects, which subclasses can then override to specify the derived type of product that will be created."*

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Pattern mostly because because

1. The naming is more precise than just new Pattern()
2. Using a factory method allows the standard implementors to change the way a Pattern is created in the future.
3. It's likely that the way it's implemented now is in some ways more efficient than just creating a new instance. Compiling a regexp to a state machine is probably an expensive process, so they will probably have found ways to mitigate this.

In general, the current wisdom is to favor static factory methods over constructors, especially in API classes.